# Summing multiple columns without specifying column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I am using a database that keeps stock levels by size in separate columns.
So, for example:

```
PRODUCT VARCHAR
QTY_1   INT
QTY_2   INT
QTY_3   INT
....
```

Rather than doing a `SUM(QTY_1+QTY_2...)`, is there a quicker way to do this through SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way or the other, you would have to list the names of your `QTY_NNN` columns. You can put it in the query, or you could define a special *calculated column* for the `QTY_TOTAL` at the table schema level, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE 
ADD QTY_TOTAL AS QTY_1 + QTY_1 + QTY_1 + ...
```

Now you can sum the `QTY_TOTAL` in all of your queries. One advantage of this approach is that if you decide to add or remove another quantity level later on, you would need to change only the definition of the `QTY_TOTAL` column; all your queries referencing this calculated column would continue working automatically.

Comment: Shit I didn't even think of that! Ooo how the simple things can be overlooked. Thanks